# Specifying the document language in Google Document AI API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud-document-ai

I'm trying to parse a handwritten document with Google Cloud Document AI. The document contains Cyrillic characters, however Document AI occasionally detects words with Latin characters. Is there way to specify the language of the document, so it will try to recognize the words in particular language regardless of the confidence?

Answer (score 2):

These are the [languages](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/languages) supported in Document AI.

Currently it's not possible to specify the language to recognize the words in a particular language in the document. It can only [detect](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/drag-and-drop#demo) language.

If you want the feature to specify the language of the document to be implemented, you can open a new [feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) on the issue tracker describing your requirement.

Answer (score 2):

There was a recent update to Document AI that supports the [`languageHints`](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1beta3/ProcessOptions#hints) parameter, which allows you to specify a language. Note: This only works when using the `v1beta3` endpoint with the [Document OCR processor](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/processors-list#processor_doc-ocr) at this time.

If the language is [supported](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/languages), then provide the `BCP-47` code for the language in the [`processOptions`](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1beta3/projects.locations.processors/process#request-body) field when [sending the processing request](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/send-request).